# How to display UIAlertView after some time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, ios10, swift2

I'm trying to display a UIAlertView after some time (like 5 minutes after doing something in the app). I'm already notifying the user if the app is closed or in a background. But I want to display a UIAlertView while the app is running. I don't want to refresh again and again. After three minutes I have to show some alert like do you want to save or not?

Comment: Please use `UIAlertController`

Comment: you should never display any `UIAlertView` anymore as it has been deprecated for a while.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It's working fine.can you help me to find the iTunes music library path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me :

```
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SONGS.displayAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
func displayAlert()
{
   self.message.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(0,animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
self.perform(#selector(displayAlert), with: nil, afterDelay: 300)
```

where display alert is the function in which you display the alert.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an alternative best approach for UIAlertView with Custom Delay is You can schedule an local Notification with timeInterval whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an answer to my question: 
I am using tap gestures with the below codes:

```
func displayAlert()
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Title", message: "This is my message.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        // add an action (button)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

        // show the alert
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(50.0, target: self, selector: #selector(SONGS.displayAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

        timer.invalidate()// stop the timer
}
```

If you set repeats:true it will display the alert every 50 seconds if u want to stop the timer you can use the timer.invalidate() wherever you want.
Thankyou