# Display alert 6 seconds after WKWebView loads

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have this but not sure how to set a timer of 6 seconds for example after `WKWebView` loads. I have this delegate `didFinish navigation`. I don't think this works:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    showAlert()
}

func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Loaded ", message: "In webview currently", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems updating countdown timer in UIAlertController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774923/problems-updating-countdown-timer-in-uialertcontroller)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display UIAlertView after some time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376627/how-to-display-uialertview-after-some-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may user `DispatchQueue asyncAfter` for this. It perform the operation after the deadline assigned to it. Below is your solution.

```
func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Loaded ", message: "In webview currently", preferredStyle: .alert)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+6.0) {
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
     Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 6, target: self, selector: #selector(showAlert), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func showAlert() {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Loaded ", message: "In webview currently", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Timer should be avoided for such tasks. better use `DispatchQueue asyncAfter`. Also you should invalidate timer once task finished else it will keep running.